# Is DecimalFormat not considering the decimal values when round it?

Tags: java

Am trying to format the amount.But the decimal values not being rounded in correct     manner.

```
public class Testing {    
    private java.text.DecimalFormat dispAmt;    
    public Testing() {                
    }    
    public static void main(String args[]){   
       Testing testing=new Testing();    
       testing.dispAmt = new java.text.DecimalFormat("##,##,##0.00");   
       // Line #8
       System.out.println(testing.dispAmt.format(1974.545));     
       System.out.println(testing.dispAmt.format(1974.535));   
    }   
 }    

OutPut:
=========
1,974.54    
1,974.54
```

In above prog what's wrong with 8th line. why it is not rounding as "1,974.55"??       where am doing mistake!! pls suggest..

Answer (score 2):

By default `DecimalFormat` uses rounding mode of `HALF_EVEN` [which](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_EVEN)

> behaves as for RoundingMode.HALF_UP if the digit to the left of the discarded fraction is odd; behaves as for RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN if it's even.

In this case the second last *least significant digit* of `4` of `1974.545` is even so the value is rounded down. Conversely, the value of `3`is odd so rounding up occurred there in the subsequent `format` statement.

Try using `RoundingMode.HALF_UP`.

```
testing.dispAmt.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Answer (score 1):

DecimalFormat#format is not rounding! it is just cutting off the values you don't display by default.

> DecimalFormat uses half-even rounding (see ROUND_HALF_EVEN) for formatting.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

you have to set the [RoundingMode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) manually

```
dispAmt.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [RoundingMode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) for the formatter by setting it using the [setRoundingMode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setRoundingMode%28java.math.RoundingMode%29) method, as by default, it does not round the value.

```
dispAmt.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING); // Ex 1
dispAmt.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP); // Ex 2 but I guess you need this in your case
```

There are many `RoundingMode`s available. Do check the docs for that.

Comment: He probably wants `RoundingMode.HALF_UP`

Comment: well, I've linked the docs in the answer. The OP can have a look at them and chose the one that suits him. Fair enough right?!

Answer (score 0):

DecimalFormat is a concrete subclass of NumberFormat that formats decimal numbers. And this doesn't round up the given numbers. [INFO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)
This just use the pattern you are given to display the number.

DecimalFormat provides rounding modes defined in [RoundingMode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#CEILING) for formatting. By default, it uses RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN.

Comment: The links is useful but the document is pretty long. Any pointers where in the documentation we can find this?

Comment: Read the first para, it just mention only about format. I edited the answer DecimalFormat supports rounding have a look.